# Overload resolution doesn't choose template when arguments are different

Tags: c++, c++11

Why the third function call of f is not using the function template?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> void f(T x, T y) { cout << "Template" << endl; }

void f(int w, int z) { cout << "Non-template" << endl; }

int main() {
   f( 1 ,  2 );
   f('a', 'b');
   f( 1 , 'b');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function template type deduction is very stringent. For each pair of function parameter and argument, deduction happens in isolation, and then deduction results are compared:

> **[temp.deduct.type]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type#2) In some cases, the deduction is done using a single set of types P and
>   A, in other cases, there will be a set of corresponding types P and A.
>   Type deduction is done independently for each P/A pair, and the
>   deduced template argument values are then combined. If type deduction
>   cannot be done for any P/A pair, or if for any pair the deduction
>   leads to more than one possible set of deduced values, or if different
>   pairs yield different deduced values, or if any template argument
>   remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template argument
>   deduction fails.

This means that the type of `x` is deduced from `1` (and int), and the type of `y` is deduced from `'b'` (a char) as though the other parameter didn't exist. This deduction yields `T = int` and `T = char` separately, and since those are different types, deduction must explicitly fail per the above paragraph.

If you *want* to call an instantiated function, you must specify `T` explicitly yourself:

```
f<int>( 1 , 'b');
f<char>( 1 , 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the third call, the two arguments are of different types, so `T` cannot be deduced, and the template function is not viable. The non-template one is then the only viable candidate.